# How to submit multiple commands as one liner in netbatch nbq commmand line

Tags: linux, perl

Can someone tell how to submit a one liner command using `nbq` command line?
Submitted multiple commands in Linux works fine but not in nbq mode as below.

```
find /nfs/disks/test_dir/ -name .snapshot -prune -o -printf '%s %p\n'" | sort -nr | head -n 50 | tee log
```

this works just find in Linux capturing the top 50 files in the check area.

```
nbq -P <pool> -q <slot> -c <machine> -J <logfile> --task-name checkdisk find /nfs/disks/test_dir/ -name .snapshot -prune -o -printf '%s %p\n'" | sort -nr | head -n 50 | tee log
```

failed as it just executing the first part without recognizing the pipe.

Comment: Could you please add link to what `nbq` is [supposed to mean]?

Comment: nbq is the netbatch command to trigger netbatch job.

Comment: Both commands have a mis-matched `"` before the first pipe.  Are those definitely what you're executing?

Answer (score 0):

When you run that whole `nbq ... find ... | sort ...`, pipeline, the shell splits the commands up as follows:

```
nbq -P <pool> -q <slot> -c <machine> -J <logfile> --task-name checkdisk find /nfs/disks/test_dir/ -name .snapshot -prune -o -printf '%s %p\n' | 
 sort -nr |
 head -n 50 |
 tee log
```

So the only thing that `nbq` sees is the bit before the first pipe.  You need to stop the shell from doing that, and instead give the whole line to `nbq`.  Without any documentation about how `nbq` parses and runs the command, it's difficult to know the right approach.

- You could tell `nbq` to execute a shell `sh`, with your original one-liner as a single argument:

  ```
  nbq -P <pool> -q <slot> -c <machine> -J <logfile> --task-name checkdisk \
    sh -c "find /nfs/disks/test_dir/ -name .snapshot -prune -o -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | head -n 50 | tee log"
  ```
- Alternatively, `nbq` may be clever enough to manage the pipeline itself (or, more likely, start another shell to do the work), in which case you only need to escape each `|` to protect it from the (current) shell.

  ```
  nbq -P <pool> -q <slot> -c <machine> -J <logfile> --task-name checkdisk \
    find /nfs/disks/test_dir/ -name .snapshot -prune -o -printf '%s %p\n' \| sort -nr \| head -n 50 \| tee log
  ```
- If all else fails, you could abandon the "one-liner" approach, and put the whole pipeline in a script:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  find /nfs/disks/test_dir/ -name .snapshot -prune -o -printf '%s %p\n' |
    sort -nr |
    head -n 50 |
    tee log
  ```

  then tell `nbq` to run that script instead:

  ```
  nbq -P <pool> -q <slot> -c <machine> -J <logfile> --task-name checkdisk \
    /path/to/top50.sh
  ```